# Procedure with out parameter (SYS_REFCURSOR) with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, iis, stored-procedures

I'm performing a migration of database, **SQL Server** to **Oracle**, in a C# application. The application mentioned, is using Entity Framework to access the database.

In this database there's a procedure that returns a *"ComplexType"*, I researched and found that Oracle does not understand the "ComplexType" and I need to perform the mapping of the output parameter in web.config, then:

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <implicitRefCursor>
        <storedProcedure schema="ALERTA_MPLUS" name="PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO">
          <refCursor name="CV_1">
            <bindInfo mode="Output" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="0" columnName="Broker" baseColumnName="Broker" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="Varchar2" providerType="Varchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="1" columnName="Companhia" baseColumnName="Companhia" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="Varchar2" providerType="Varchar2" columnSize="100" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="2" columnName="Metrica" baseColumnName="Metrica" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="Varchar2" providerType="Varchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="3" columnName="Q1" baseColumnName="Q1" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="4" columnName="Q2" baseColumnName="Q2" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="5" columnName="Q3" baseColumnName="Q3" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="6" columnName="Q4" baseColumnName="Q4" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
          </refCursor>
        </storedProcedure>
      </implicitRefCursor>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

This mapping worked perfectly in the development environment, but when I passed the application for approval gave the following error:

[image: Error]
I've tried some solutions but none was successful:

- ODAC installed on the server approval;
- Searching, I found the Oracle documentation that indicates the mapping that way:

  ```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursor.CV_1" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.0" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Broker;BaseColumnName=Broker;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.1" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Companhia;BaseColumnName=Companhia;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.2" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Metrica;BaseColumnName=Metrica;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.3" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q1;BaseColumnName=Q1;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.4" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q2;BaseColumnName=Q2;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.5" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q3;BaseColumnName=Q3;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.6" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q4;BaseColumnName=Q4;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
  ```

This is code return the following error (in all environments):

```
 ORA-06550: line 1, colunm 8: PLS-00306:
 wrong number or types of arguments in call to
 'PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO' ORA-06550: line 1, colunm 8: PL/SQL:
 Statement ignored;
```

- I published the application on another machine (another developer) and also worked;

Some information that I think are necessary:

- Visual Studio 2013;
- Oracle.DataAcess.dll version 4.121.1.0;
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll version 4.121.1.0;
- ISS 7.0;
- Pool - Enable 32-bit Applications **true**;

If you can help me...

Very thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trials and errors managed to solve. I do not know if it is the best solution but worked.

In `machine.config` exists a definition of `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>`:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>
```

So I added this declaration in `web.config` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I had the same issue with a console app, and this fixed it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this showed me the way to a solution.

The cause of the issue was that I had installed the `OracleManagedDataAccessClient` through NUGET but someone else had done a native install of the client.  When the client was installed, it created an entry in the Machine.Config.  When NUGET installed it created an entry in the Web.config.  When trying to execute, I received an error that the section for:

```
 <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

Already existed.  I commented it out and my service worked but Oracle would fail with the error:

> "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call"

When the client was installed it was an earlier version of Oracle so the entry in the Machine.config was:

```
 <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.**1**.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

Since I commented the entry in `web.config`, the application used the `machine.config` entry which did not match the actual version.

I modified the entry in the `machine.config` to match the web.config and everything now works.